# How to run a Java code using windows task scheduler?

Tags: java, windows-task-scheduler

I hava a java code in my sytem. I have to run the code and execute the function inside the code every one hour since startup of the sytem. How can I do this using windows task scheduler?

Comment: Is your java program packaged as an executable jar?

Comment: You can run this like any other program. Or even better: convert it into a daemon using nssm and use an internal scheduler.